# How to determine if a RAMDisk will be benificial and what to put on it?

Tags: windows-7, memory, ramdisk

How much RAM is necessary for a RAMDisk and how does one determine how much to allocate? Also what programs benefit from being put on a RAMDisk since the contents is lost when the machine is powered off? I was thinking of putting some Microsoft Office products on the RAMDisk, for example Word, Since the user always chooses where the documents are saved. I heard on Windows 7 RAMDisk is obsolete since [SuperFetch](http://www.osnews.com/story/21471) does it job, is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 10):

(Forward: This post is written from a performance perspective. Ultrasawblade brings up a good point about the use of RAM disks to keep files from ever being written to disk for security reasons, and this post does not apply to those situations.)

It is as simple as that, and has been since before Windows XP. There is absolutely no need for a RAM disk in Windows 7, and very little need in Windows XP/Vista (these don't have SuperFetch which pre-fetches data, but they do have disk caching):

[image]

Standby memory (dark blue bar) is this disk cache. Windows will automatically manage it such that it fills as much RAM as it can without causing problems. It will dynamically shrink when applications need the memory, and grow when applications don't need the memory.

Every major OS has had disk caching for years. The only really new thing with SuperFetch is that it can guess ahead of time which blocks you might need, and copy them to the disk cache before you use them.

To get an idea of how effective disk caching is, in a 72-hour timeframe, applications on my desktop request about 5TB of data; however, **97.5%** of that is served from a 32GB disk cache-- That means that only 160GB of data was actually read from the disk. (note, the above image is not from my desktop)

There is absolutely **NO WAY** I could manually select 32GB of data and have it cover 97.5% of the data requested by all applications on my system, including the kernel and services.

---

The only benefit to a RAM disk is that you get to choose which files are loaded ahead of time; You can load office onto it, and then office will load really fast. This is what is most frequently deceiving about RAM disks being "faster".

However, that comes at a very high cost. Loading all of office onto a RAM disk wastes a lot of memory: There are many files which are installed with office, but which are never used in normal use (templates, help files, themes other than the default, etc.). These are now wasting precious memory that could otherwise be used to cache files that you *are* using frequently. Or even parts of files. With a RAM disk, there's no way to cache something like the windows event log or the master ntfs file table. These both can be used hundreds of times per second in normal scenarios.

Disk caching is so powerful that you can't even turn it off in Windows; I honestly wish you could, just so that I could show people what it's like if they replace their disk cache with a RAM disk.

Answer (score 4):

- Most RAMDisk software I've encountered lets you allocate any amount of RAM you want.  So the amount you allocate is according to your needs and what you want to put on it.
- RAM disks will speed up file access.  With executables, the usual situation is that they are loaded and then not accessed anymore.  Putting programs on there may not see much benefit other than initial start up time, unless your program has a lot of .DLL's that are always switched in and out - with typical PC memory being in the 4GB+ range this is not likely worth worrying about.  Putting files the programs work with may see some speed increase.
- SuperFetch preloads parts of programs that you use often in order to make programs launch quicker.  If you are trying to make programs launch quicker with a RAMDisk, I believe SuperFetch would eventually do as good as a job once it learns what you use all the time.  Note that RAM disks are volatile and you would have to recopy files each boot.
- Windows caches bits of files in RAM not in use by programs.  Trying to do this yourself with a RAM disk may not result in much improvement unless you A) have a specific program that reads and writes a file repeatedly, B) have no need for this file to exist on disk, and C) the program cannot be reconfigured in any other way.  So it's a bit of a "hack" maybe to get an older program acting better, though I can't think of a specific example.  Note that having a RAM disk reduces your available RAM to the system and other programs so you might be "robbing Peter to pay Paul" with your RAM.
- One good use of RAM disks is to tell a program to write there in order to ensure that the data never touches a disk.  Setting a program to use a temp directory on a RAM drive keeps that data off of a disk if security or privacy are extreme concerns.

Answer (score 1):

@ultrasawblade and @darthandroid have are correct.  However, I want to boil it down even more.  The best use of a RAM disk is to hold files that are frequently accessed - especially writing.  Applications like Visual Studio, Adobe Creative Suites (temp file location), and games can  benefit greatly from RAM disks.

As for SuperFetch, it is not a replacement for a RAM disk.  SuperFetch uses an algorithm to place files in its cache.  SuperFetch can "miss" a file.  A RAM disk will *never* miss a file since all the files are copied to RAM.

Comment: Disk caching already keeps a copy of frequently accessed files in unused memory - there's no need for a RAMdisk for this. Also, a RAM disk will miss every file not placed on it.

Comment: disk caching is not 100% reliable, as a file can get flushed.  As for the second statement, thats true, but avoidable if you set it up correctly.

Comment: Files only get flushed if you manually flush or there's a higher-priority file that you're using more often and no more space in memory. As for the second statement, it's not avoidable. If you don't copy the file to the RAM disk, then it won't be loaded from the RAM disk. If you find a utility which automatically copies files to your RAM disk, then congratulations, you've recreated a less effective form of Windows' disk caching, and you might as well just turn the RAMdisk off.

Comment: thats not true at all.

Answer (score 0):

I have 24gb's of Ram and have created a Ramdisk of 5gb's to store Pale Moon's memory usage, page file, TMP, and Temp files. Here are some of my pointers.

1. I enjoy playing WOT and to start the game and just get to the garage and then shut the game down I "changed" and "deleted" TMP entrys 1016 times... That's not even playing it. Download Activity Indicator to try it yourself.
2. My 7200rpm Western Digital hard drive has an average reading speed of 105mb's, My SSD drive has a reading speed of 525mb's, and my Ramdisk... 8.1GB'S of reading speed. Download HD_Speed.exe to try it yourself... Run as Admin.
3. Page file is set for a minimum 256mb's and max of 2048mb's... just what Samsung says to do if you have more then 4096mb's of ram. It started at 256 and has never been increased. So if you have plenty of room... Do it!!
4. Anytime you can take away from writing to any of your drives and move them to a Ramdisk is going to be an excellent choice!!!
5. I use Softperfect and it has run flawless and free from the start.
6. If you have a SSD then you do not need Pre-Fetch or Super-Fetch (I have a Samsung SSD and they recommend not using either) but if you don't, even with a Ramdisk I would.
7. As far as reloading Ramdisk every time you reboot... The only thing that gets reloaded on the Ramdisk is the 256mb of page file and I don't even notice. Everything from Pale Moon's memory and Temp/TMP files are loading as you go... 7 1/2gbs faster loading time!!!!
8. I don't reboot my system that often at all so that makes it so that my system has the history of what I'm using and BAM it's there!!!

To each their own but I have had the best running Laptop (ASUS G75VX w/8.1) and Ramdisk is a big, huge part of it!!