# Behaviour of the swap file and RAM usage

Tags: windows-7, memory

I have 6GB of RAM on my computer but when I'm using heavy programs, window shove some of the data used by the program in the swap file. Naturaly, the program run much slower.

To avoid this, I tried to disable my swap file. But when I reach 4GB used on my 6GB, window tell me to close the program that I want to use!

So my question is : If I'm disabling my swap file, how to fully use my RAM?
And how to avoid usage of swap file for certain programs?

Comment: How much of your RAM is usable? Is this a 32bit OS? You can check both of these in the System Properties window. (Hit Win + E, click on "System properties" in the top left corner).

Comment: I've a 64 bit OS, and my 6GB of RAM are fully detected (and used) by window

Comment: It sounds like your page file is to small and the error message you received indicates you ran out of **virtual** memory not physical memory.  If these programs are 32-bit processes then they can only use 4GB.

Comment: If the program you run is itself 32-bit, it will not be able to use more than 4 GB, regardless of 64 bit OS. This is probably not the case though, since the swap file is reported to help.

Comment: What programs are you trying to run? Besides web browsers and VMs, I can't think of anything that would use so much RAM by itself.

Comment: @bob, try to refine your statements. How much RAM does your program use when swap file is enabled? What is the exact message windows gives you when 4GB of RAM are in use? What is the name of this program anyway?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't think my swap file is too small, I never seen it used more than 60% (Its maximum capacity is around 6GB too)

Comment: @Dmitry I've this type of message when reaching 4GB of used ram when my swap is disabled : http://blogs.technet.com/blogfiles/markrussinovich/WindowsLiveWriter/PushingtheLimitsofWindowsVirtualMemory_917D/image30.png . Some programs like games (gta v, rust) or when using multiple VMs with VMware can need to use up to 2GB of swap memory (~30% of its total capacity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Windows reports that a program is using a large amount of memory and you should close it because Windows is low on memory, then that means your virtual memory (RAM + swap/page file) are approaching maximum capacity. You need to either add a page file / increase the size of the page file, add more memory, or close down programs that you are not using.

As a general rule of thumb, disabling your page file will **not** improve system performance holistically. The operating system only moves things into swap if they are being used *less* than the data that it wants to move into RAM. Disabling the page file means that Windows cannot move low-priority data out of RAM to make more room for high-priority data. This is *very bad* for performance.

If you want the page file to be used less, then add more RAM, or close down programs that are running in the background. Anything else (shrinking page file, using a RAM disk, etc.) will make overall system performance worse.

Comment: Then I don't understand why I get the message saying that I'm low on memory when 4GB are used... I've got 6GB! I don't think that 60% of used memory can be seen as a low memory state? But I guess you're right when you say that I'll have to add more RAM...

Comment: You might find my answer [here](http://superuser.com/a/610205/19841) relevant - If Windows is complaining that it's low on memory, then that 2GB is most definitely not free. It may not be process memory, but that does not mean it's unused (Mapped files for example do not show up under a process, and are categorized as "standby" memory - people frequently confuse "Standby" and "Free" memory because most systems have very little "Free" memory, even when they are idle (as they should)).